# search companies tab missing arrow with drop down for keyword filter

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm a bit confused about the **search jobs** and **search companies** tabs on jobs.  These two should work very similarly, but I have found a lot of discrepancies on these two, especially search companies.

In this case the keyword filter on the tab search companies is missing the drop down filter any job type, permanent, contract.

Answer (score 1):

It's a technical issue without current architecture. It's hard to get working as that data specifically only applies to job listings at the moment.